# Trouble calling member function from another object

Tags: c++, function, oop, member

I've begun coding in C++ some months ago and now I have been trying to code this one Tic Tac Toe game in an OO manner, however I have had some trouble calling a member function from, let's say just for the sake of the argument, class A through another member function from class B.

Here is a piece of code just to clear it all out:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
 private:

    char cBlocks[9];

 public:

    void setA(int nBlock, const char cCharacter)
    {
        cBlocks[nBlock] = cCharacter;
    }
};

class B
{
 private:

    char cB;

 public:

    char getB()
    {
        return cB;
    }

    void makePlay(int nB)
    {
        const char cChar = getB();

        A::setA(nB, cChar);
    }
};
```

So, when I try to make this call, from within the B::makePlay(int) function:

```
A::setA(nB, cChar);
```

The following error is displayed: "Call to non-static member function without an object argument" .

How can I solve this ? What is wrong ?
All help is appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `setA` on an instance of class `A`

```
A a;
a.setA(nB, cChar);
```

Comment: Ok, but what if I don't pretend to create this instance of object A within the B::makePlay(int) member function and instead I want to create it in the main() function ?

Comment: You'd need to pass the `A` instance into `B::makePlay` in that case.  (Alternatively, you could give `B` a member of type `A` and use that)